# Parsing string with Lua table structure

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a string with this structure (it's Lua Table)

```
{['Name1']={score=235,x=6,y=88},['Name2']={score=112,x=12,y=55},['Name3']={score=15,x=15,y=56},}
```

For easy to read:

```
{['Name1']={score=235,x=6,y=88},
['Name2']={score=112,x=12,y=55},
['Name3']={score=15,x=15,y=56},} <--there might be more entries than these three of course
```

And I need to find the values Name1, score, x and y for each name.

I believe regex could do it but I am terrible at using it. So if anyone more experienced gives me some pattern, I would be very happy.

Comment: Use `/\[\'(\w+)\'\]={score=(\d+),x=(\d+),y=(\d+)/`

Answer (score 0):

You could test your regex with some online tool such as [this one](https://regex101.com/)

You could also make it easier for you and not use regex and split the string by this substring **"},["** and you would get some array of values with substrings:

```
0 -> {['Name1']={score=235,x=6,y=88 
1 -> 'Name2']={score=112,x=12,y=55
2 -> 'Name3']={score=15,x=15,y=56},}
```

Then you could also split each entry by **"]={"** and you will have

```
0.0 -> {['Name1'
0.1 -> score=235,x=6,y=88 
1.0 -> 'Name2'
1.1 -> score=112,x=12,y=55
2.0 -> 'Name3'
2,1 -> score=15,x=15,y=56},}
```

... and so on...

This is not a pretty solution but it will help you to achieve your task without regex.